# Copying a specific range with bolded segment into a specific range on another spreadsheet while preserving the bolded segment

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

### What I have

On a google spreadsheet, I have a range (A1:B1), like this:

**spreadsheetA | sheet1**

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Hello world, **this text is bolded**, while the rest is not | Some text |

### What I want

I want to copy the text into a range (D3:E3) in a separate google spreadsheet, so it will have the same text **and** the same bolded section(s), like this:

**spreadsheetB | sheet2**

|  | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Hello world, **this text is bolded**, while the rest is not | Some text |

### What I have now

I am currently using `.setValues()` which results in copying only the plain text (as `.copyTo()` can only be used in the same spreadsheet), like this:

**spreadsheetB | sheet2**

|  | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Hello world, this text is bolded, while the rest is not | Some text |

**The (simplified) code for reference:**

```
function syncToSpreadsheetB(sheet1) { // found under spreadSheetA
  var spreadSheetB = SpreadsheetApp.openById('spreadSheetB_id');
  var sheet2 = spreadSheetB.getSheetByName('sheet2');

  if (sheet2 === null) return;

  sheet2.getRange(3,4,1,2).setValues(sheet1.getRange(1,1,1,2).getValues());
}
```

I know that there is the [RichTextValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value) class, but wasn't sure how to use it for what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation, how about using RichTextValue? This has also already mentioned in your question. So, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var spreadsheetA = SpreadsheetApp.openById('###');
  var sheet1 = spreadsheetA.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var srcRange = sheet1.getRange(1,1,1,2); // This range is from your script.
  var srcRichTextValues = srcRange.getRichTextValues();

  var spreadSheetB = SpreadsheetApp.openById('spreadSheetB_id');
  var sheet2 = spreadSheetB.getSheetByName('sheet2');
  sheet2.getRange(3,4,1,2).setRichTextValues(srcRichTextValues); // This range is from your script.
}
```

#### References:

- [getRichTextValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getrichtextvalues)
- [setRichTextValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setrichtextvaluesvalues)

Comment: I totally missed those methods! Thanks!

Comment: @Yaniv Aflalo Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.